# python: working statistically with strings, numbers and NaN at the same time?

Tags: python, string, pandas, statistics, numbers

(I didn't find even a similar question)

In the df, some columns have the values `[NaN, 0, 1.32, 2, 3.4, 5, "No contact"]` (all of them included in each one) and they have different meanings (So, I can't replace "No contact" with NaN or 0, for example). Then, how can I have a statistic summary in columns with numbers, strings, and NaN? Any advice to work statistically with columns with numbers, strings, and NaN? Or any guide or documentation you could suggest?

(pandas.df.describe() doesn't work statistically on them)

In specific:
- A statistic summary for the whole df (like df.describe())
- Variance and standard deviation with conditions

Thanks !

Comment: You are going to need to be way more specific than "work statistically with". What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Variance and standard deviation are defined only for numbers. What do you expect to calculate for the non-numeric values?

Comment: My only guess is to try something like this: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').describe()` this will convert strings to NaN for the calculation but it should maintain the original dataframe if you call `print(df)`